# "No module named" after pip install tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip

I've been trying to fix this problem for a WHILE now. I've been looking online and trying anything I could find – from uninstalling and reinstalling pip, to uninstalling and reinstalling python – and I still can't find **any** solution. This only began after I updated my MacBook Pro to macOS Catalina (currently on 10.15.5) so I'm thinking this might be a permissions issue. Basically, I'll pip3 install a python module (or pip install – I've tried both, neither work) and I still get the "no module named ____" error afterwards. Currently on VSCode, but I've tried Idle, or even just running the file in terminal and nothing works.

Let me know what I could do, or if there's any more info I should provide!

Edit: Here is what I get for "which python" and "which python3", I dunno if that's related to the problem in any way but here you go:

```
$ which python
> /Users/asaflebovic/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
$ which python3
> /Users/asaflebovic/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

Comment: Check your Env and use which python; you might be having multiple instances of Python? Plus type python/python3 etc on the terminal and see the preamble;

Comment: @Aditya here is what I get:
$ which python
> /usr/bin/python

$ which python3
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3

Anything I can do to fix that? Is that wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong; It's just we generally don't use system python; You should install Anaconda; and then it will be easy; Install Anaconda; then Add the VSCode Python Extension; From the left bottom; select the correct python interpreter; and you should be set (it will look like Python <version> base:conda)

Comment: @Aditya just did that and it's not working:


```
asaflebovic@asafs-Air-2:~/Desktop/Development$ /Users/asaflebovic/opt/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/asaflebovic/Desktop/Development/python/translatebot.py
>>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/asaflebovic/Desktop/Development/python/translatebot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tweepy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tweepy'
```

Comment: @Aditya Yup, I double checked...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install a package inside anaconda environment, I think you should have used `conda` instead of `pip`. As for checking whether tweepy is really installed or not, activate anaconda environment and then run `conda list`. If tweepy is listed there then you should be able to import tweepy.

And be sure to remember when you run the code you should always activate the environment where the package required by that code is located.

*ps: actually you didn't need to install anaconda.*